# Get "average" of several randomly broken copies of a same file

Tags: python, file, bitwise-operators

Due to a broken controller, files get randomly corrupted while being downloaded from a USB flash drive.
I have downloaded several copies of the same file and the errors seem to be generally unique and random for each copy.

Thus, I need a script to compare several (3 to 5) broken copies of a same file (~100 Mb in size each) and 'vote' for correct value for each byte, appending it afterwards to an output file.

Is there a quick and easy way to implement this in Python 3?

Comment: This only works if the corruption is limited to modifying individual bytes, not adding or deleting bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Zip the byte streams together, and use a `Counter` to get the consensus byte at each position.

```
from functools import partial
from collections import Counter
from contextlib import ExitStack
from mmap import mmap, PROT_READ

fnames = ["t1.txt", "t2.txt"]

with ExitStack() as stack:
    fhs = [stack.enter_context(open(f, 'rb')) for f in fnames]
    out = stack.enter_context(open("fixed", 'wb'))
    streams = [mmap(f.fileno(), 0, prot=PROT_READ) for f in fhs]
    for bs in zip(*streams):
        c = Counter(bs)
        out.write(c.most_common(1)[0][0])
```

Comment: Great thanks, the script worked!

I am very bad at functional programming, so I would prefer the original code, but it didn't work for me, despite me correcting a missing index in the 'most common' method.

The second, functional version plowed through four 100Mb files in ~13mins and successfully produced an output file that I haven't forgotten to close in the end.

The third version did the same in ~11mins, after I have changed `prot=PROT_READ` parameter to `access=ACCESS_READ` , as I am using Windows.